# How to access/split items in a column that contains a list

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I received a dataset with a structure similar to this (I understand that this structure is not typical.)

*The following code is just to generate an example of a dataframe that looks like my data.*

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'foo': 123, 'bar': [1, 2]}, 
        {'foo': 456, 'bar': [1, 2]} 
    ] 
)


   foo    item
0  123  [1, 2]
1  456  [1, 2]
```

Is there an easy way to:

- access items in bar.. like df.bar[1], resulting in 2 ?
  (this clearly does not work)
- or split the bar column into something like bar.0, bar.1, etc..

Ideally, I would like to plot all items in bar[0] vs bar[1]

Note the list in bar is not limited to 2 items and the number can vary a bit.

Comment: Thanks! Two great answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. Use [`str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.get.html)

```
tmp.bar.str.get(0)

0    1
1    1
Name: bar, dtype: int64

tmp.bar.str.get(1)

0    2
1    2
Name: bar, dtype: int64
```

---

To split, use pandas DataFrame constructor

```
col_names = ['bar.0', 'bar.1'] # Notice you can dinamically create this if needed
pd.DataFrame(tmp.bar.values.tolist(), columns=col_names)

    bar.0   bar.1
0   1       2
1   1       2
```

Answer (score 2):

For your second request, you could apply `pd.Series`, and concatenate with your original dataframe:

```
>>> pd.concat((tmp,tmp.bar.apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('bar_')), axis=1)
      bar  foo  bar_0  bar_1
0  [1, 2]  123      1      2
1  [1, 2]  456      1      2
```

This works even if there are a variable number of elements in `bar`:

```
>>> tmp
         bar  foo
0  [1, 2, 3]  123
1     [1, 2]  456

>>> pd.concat((tmp,tmp.bar.apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('bar_')), axis=1)
         bar  foo  bar_0  bar_1  bar_2
0  [1, 2, 3]  123    1.0    2.0    3.0
1     [1, 2]  456    1.0    2.0    NaN
```